# How to use turborepo for individual public node modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, turborepo

If I have a target project structure like this one

```
./project               (name 'project', private)
   ./apps
      ./playground      (name '@project/playground', private)
   ./packages
      ./base            (name '@project/base', public)
      ./plugin-a        (name '@project/plugin-a', public)
      ./plugin-b        (name '@project/plugin-b', public)
```

I am considering using [Turborepo](https://turborepo.org/) because of it's ease of use, however the default layout has a `./packages/ui` with TypeScript files directly at the root of this package, so I have a few questions:

1. Can TypeScript modules be published to npm and be used by non-TS projects? (my intuition says "no" to this one without transpiling sources, therefore:)
2. What should be the content of `package.json` of these packages be so they can be published to `npm` and be used by both TypeScript and JavaScript projects?

I assume an ideal solution would be to have a `src` folder containing the TypeScript files, and a `dist` folder containing transpiled JavaScript, is that correct?

Comment: Did you find answers to your questions? I was wondering about the same things.

Comment: @Magnus yes, look at this project : https://github.com/yanickrochon/foo-auth